# Unreal Engine - Issue with Variable Type Recognition

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I'm currently working on a project in Unreal Engine and facing an issue with variable type recognition. In my project, I have two Blueprint classes: `BP_PlayerBall` and `BP_GameHUD`.

In `BP_PlayerBall`, I've created a variable called `HUD REF`, with its type set to `BP_GameHUD`. The "Instance Editable" checkbox is checked to allow me to set it externally.

However, when I try to set the `HUD REF` variable in the `BP_GameHUD` class, it unexpectedly appears as a Boolean type instead of the expected `BP_GameHUD` type. This is causing conflicts and preventing me from setting the variable correctly.

I've already verified the variable type in `BP_PlayerBall`, saved the Blueprint, and reopened the `BP_GameHUD` class. I've also ensured that I have placed instances of `BP_GameHUD` in my level.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue or if I missed any crucial steps. Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

"What did you try: I created a Blueprint class named BP_PlayerBall and added a variable called HUD REF, setting its type to BP_GameHUD. I also checked the 'Instance Editable' checkbox to allow external setting of the variable. I verified the variable type, saved the Blueprint, and reopened the BP_GameHUD class. Additionally, I placed instances of BP_GameHUD in my level."

"What were you expecting: I expected that I would be able to set the HUD REF variable in the BP_GameHUD class, and it would recognize its type correctly as BP_GameHUD, allowing me to interact with it as expected."

"What actually resulted: However, when I tried to set the HUD REF variable in the BP_GameHUD class, it appeared as a Boolean type instead of BP_GameHUD. This unexpected behavior is causing conflicts, and I'm unable to set the variable correctly."